# Empty Info Windows Google Maps Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, xslt

Someone knows how to solve this problem?

Chrome:

[image: View with chrome]

Firefox:

[image: View with Firefox]

There is my javascript code:

Init the map, and define addMarker function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var markers = [];
    var markerCluster;

    function initMap(){
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.6130537, 2.8864253),
            zoom: 9,
        });
    }

    function addmarker(latilongi, info, last) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latilongi,
            title: 'titol',
            clickable: true,
            map: map
        });
        marker.info = info;
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          marker.info.open(map, marker);
        });
        markers.push(marker);

        if(last==1){
            markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
        }
    }

    initMap();
</script>
```

Create Info Window and call add marker function:

```
<script>
    var lat = <xsl:value-of select="coordenadas/latitud"/>
    var long = <xsl:value-of select="coordenadas/longitud"/>
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);

    var contentString = '<div id="content" style="width:100%; max-width:400px;">'+
        '<div id="siteNotice">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<a href="#"><h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading"><xsl:value-of select="nombre"/></h1></a>'+
        '<h4 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading"><xsl:value-of select="poblacion"/></h4>'+
        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
        '<a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/fondo1.jpg" style="width:100%; max-width:400px;"><xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="imagenes/url"/></xsl:attribute></img></a>'+
        '<hr></hr>'+
        '<p><xsl:value-of select="descripcion"/></p>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>';

    var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
    });
    <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
      addmarker(myLatlng,info,1);
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
      addmarker(myLatlng,info,0);
    </xsl:if>
</script>
```

I am using XSLT and javascript. This final condition position() = last(), is to know when I have to cluster the marks.

As you can see with Chrome and Safari is working, but with Firefox it displays an empty windows, and the console don't display any error.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a URL online where we can see the problem?

Comment: No, for the moment it is local.

Comment: Please provide some more details, how does the `xsl:output` look, how do you run the XSLT, with Javascript or by using a processing instruction '<?xml-stylesheet ...?>` in a XML document? Does the Javascript code you have work in a plain HTML document with Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to change the approach, if the XSLT is supposed to create some HTML then do that in pure XSLT, not with XSLT creating snippets of HTML strings you concatenate in Javascript.

So try to move the HTML construction to pure XSLT before the script block e.g.

```
<div id="content" style="width:100%; max-width:400px;">
  ...
  <a href="#"><h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading"><xsl:value-of select="nombre"/></h1></a>
</div>

<script>
    var lat = <xsl:value-of select="coordenadas/latitud"/>
    var long = <xsl:value-of select="coordenadas/longitud"/>
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);

    var content = document.getElementById('content');

    var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: content 
    });
    <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
      addmarker(myLatlng,info,1);
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
      addmarker(myLatlng,info,0);
    </xsl:if>
</script>
```